# реализация модели mvc php

Tags: php, mvc, view, controller, model

Есть проблема подключения модели в контроллерe.Я создал основной метод для подключения файлов моделеи который вызывается при необходимости.
Проблмa находится в методе `actionServiceinfo()` в который подключается `requireModel()` .Помогите с проблемой .Заранне спасибо

Вот Код

index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('Core/Bootstrap.php');
require_once('Core/Controller.php');
require_once('Core/Model.php');
require_once('Core/View.php');
require_once('Core/Database.php');
require_once('config/Database.php');
require_once('config/Secure.php');

$bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
```

Core/Bootstrap.php

```
private $controller = NULL;

    private $action = NULL;

    private $params = array();

    private function parseUrl(){

        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {

             $url = Secure::secureUrl($_GET['url']);
             return $url;

        }else{

             require_once('controller/HomeController.php');
             $object = new HomeController;
             $object->actionIndex();
             return false;
        }
    }

    public function __construct(){

        $explode = explode('/', $this->parseUrl());

        if (isset($explode[0])) {

              if (file_exists("controller/".ucfirst($explode[0])."Controller.php")) {

                       $this->controller = ucfirst($explode[0])."Controller";
                       require_once("controller/".$this->controller.".php");

              }else{

                    require_once('controller/ErrorController.php');
                    $object = new ErrorController();
                    $object->actionIndex();
                    return false;
              }
        }


        $object = new $this->controller;


        if (isset($explode[2])) {

             if (method_exists($object, "action".ucfirst($explode[1]))) {

                     $this->action = "action".ucfirst($explode[1]);
                     $this->param = $explode[2];

                     call_user_func([$object,$this->action], $this->param);

             }else{

                    require_once('controller/ErrorController.php');
                    $object = new ErrorController();
                    $object->actionIndex();
                    return false;
              }

        }else{

              if (isset($explode[1])) {

                   if (method_exists($object, "action".ucfirst($explode[1]))) {

                            $this->action = "action".ucfirst($explode[1]);

                            call_user_func([$object,$this->action]);


                   }else{

                         require_once('controller/ErrorController.php');
                         $object = new ErrorController();
                         $object->actionIndex();
                         return false;
                    }

              }else{

                  $object->actionIndex();

              }
        }

    }



}
```

Core/Controller.php

```
class Controller{

    public function __construct(){

       $this->view = new View();
    }


     public function requireModel($name){

        $pathe = "model/" . $name . "Model.php";

        if (file_exists($pathe)) {

            require_once($pathe);

            $this->model = new $name."Model";

        }
    }
}
```

Core/Model.php

```
class Model{


     public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new Database();
    }

}
```

Core/Database.php

```
class Database extends PDO {


    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(DB_TYPE . ":host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }

}
```

Controller/ServiceController.php

```
class ServiceController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        $this->view->render('Service/index');
    }


    public function actionServiceinfo($id = NULL){
        $this->requireModel('Service');
        $serviceModel = new ServiceModel();
        $serviceInfo = $serviceModel->userInfo($id);
        $this->view->render('Service/info',$serviceInfo);
        print_r($serviceInfo);
    }


}
```

Model/ServiceModel.php

```
class ServieModel extends Model{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public  function userInfo($id){
       $studentPrepare = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE service_id = :service_id");
       $studentPrepare->execute([':service_id' => $id]);
       return $studentPrepare->fetch();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Есть проблема подключения модели в контроллерe.` .. и она заключается в том, что модели не должны подключаться в контроллерах :)

Comment: Это как????????

Comment: @Lexx918 модель загружается в контроллере=) Допустим у вас контроллер который использует пользователя и его записи, а контроллер это архив, для этого вы загрузите две модели пользователь и записи в контроллер архивов

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер - это ввод. Играет ту же роль, что и, например, клавиатура, мышка, сканер, микрофон или вебкамера. Контроллер, как устройство ввода, не должен ничего знать про место хранения или способ инициализации классов ваших моделей. Об этом знает абстракция уровнем выше, приложение.

Раз уж вы взялись за реализацию MVC, начните сразу с нормального централизованного загрузчика классов. Для этого в пыхе уже давно есть готовые функции автолоада. Часть устарела, смотрите сразу на свежие в пакете spl, - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Как именно хранить и загружать файлы - дело ваше, но сообществом приняты стандарты, среди которых есть и канонический автолоадер - https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Можете просто разобраться в описании стандарта и взять из него же уже готовый пример (ссылка в конце статьи).

Либо, если коротко ответить на ваш вопрос, - файл модели не грузится, потому что или нет файла или путь к нему указан неверно. Выведите отладку и посмотрите по какому именно пути вы ищите файл. Скорее всего там банальная проблема с путями.

P.S. require_once - не функция, а языковая конструкция, и скобки для аргумента не нужны, пишите просто `require_once 'имя_файла.php';`, без скобок.